# Use KnockoutJS ViewModel in External JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How do you create a KO.JS ViewModel in an external JS file then use it in an html file? This seems like such a simple thing but I cannot get it to work and cannot find any clear information on how to do this. If I have overlooked I apologize and will remove this if someone can point me to the answer.

EXTERNAL vm:

```
var myApp = (function (myApp) {
myApp.ReportViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.test = ko.observable();
  }
}(myApp || {}));
```

Seperate HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My Page</title></head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind='value: test'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: test"> </span>!</h2>

<!-- reference this *before* initializing -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="myApp.js"></script>

<!-- fire off your app -->
<script>
    ($function(){
       var reportVM = new myApp.ReportViewModel();
       ko.applyBindings(reportVM);
    });
</script>
```

***EDIT*** 
I have made the suggested changes. This is what my project now looks like but it is still not working. Also the knockout.js code is not running at all.

Comment: Have you referenced your script file in your main html with `<script type="text/javascript" src="EXTERNAL.js"></script>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path. As @nemesv comments you may need to reference the external JS before you can use it. In addition, I'd recommend creating a namespace object for your app. All this together would look like this:

```html
<html>
<head><title>My Page</title></head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind='value: test'/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: test"> </span>!</h2>

    <!-- reference this first -->
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- reference this *before* initializing -->
    <script src="myApp.js"></script>

    <!-- fire off your app -->
    <script>
        $(function(){
           var reportVM = new myApp.ReportViewModel();
           ko.applyBindings(reportVM);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS. Note that I changed `new reportVM` to just `reportVM` in the second line. It's just a var at that point, no need to "new" it. In addition, I've fixed the parentheses placement on that bit of script.

And in `myApp.js` have this:

```
var myApp = (function (myApp) {
    myApp.ReportViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.test = ko.observable("Testing 123");
    }

    return myApp;
}(myApp || {}));
```

This way things like `ReportViewModel` and other constructor functions for your app won't linger in the global namespace, but will be part of the `myApp` object ("namespace", if you will).

Comment: I have tried this and it is still not working. I even created new files and used the exact code you have here with the needed corrections and it still does not work

Comment: Apologies. First, I should've mentioned to include Knockout and jQuery. Second, you had a typo in the main script bit which I copied. Third, I had an error in my JS example, I forgot to return the namespace such that it's saved again. I've [fixed things in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19576000/revisions), please have another look.

Comment: PS. If you say "it still does not work" it helps if you include your debugging info, the console explained would mention all the various errors.

Comment: the return statement did it. Thanks, the error in the ready function was not in my code, I typed it wrong here when messing with the formatting to get everything to fit in to the code block

Comment: Okidoki. Glad it helped!