# MVC kendoUI KnockoutJs jQuery and 'Code Clutter'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, kendo-ui

In my new assignment I have a project which was initially developed by developers who are no more working with my employer now.

The project is a website developed in ASP.NET MVC, KENDO UI -GRID  etc alongwith knockoutJS and extensive jQuery.

In various views  block is added to run page specfic code and various knockoutJS code as well Kendo UI is mixed with HTML Code.
Addition to this there are page level and inline CSS code. There is too much clutter in this code base.

Here I am making a attempt to make this code testable or maintainable so that easier to read, understand and if required can have more code coverage for UI code.

My thoughts are to have JS file for each View Like CreateLocation.js etc etc
This Js file should have all my Js And Kendo Code.

And I shall be able to write unit test using Jasmine for the functions in this JS File.

Any Guidance or blogs or code reference to go on this route..

Comment: really Close? at least mention some links if you know before voting to close.

Comment: That is probably why they voted to close, you ask for links and opinions rather than a question to be answered. Stackoverflow is not meant for questions like "can you show me a tutorial for...", have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see if you can make the question easier to answer.

Comment: Ok thanks.. close it I think i have to keep on doing Google.. as SO policies are restricting me to ask boarder question. I think it will be great if some one can suggest me to narrow down this question so that i will get my answer to make my code more clean and maintainable

Comment: What you ask for i so broad that it would really take a class at university to cover it. Therefore it's hard to answer and even harder to answer correctly. Google should be able to provide you with the information you need, but I suspect you'll need to read a lot before actually being able to solve your issue. I hope you'll figure it out and when concrete questions arise, do not hesitat to put up another question here =)

Comment: Thaks a lot.   ! Time to en-roll for university course now

Comment: Below Link has given me some information...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575729/use-knockoutjs-viewmodel-in-external-javascript-file